# PDF of a variable in a function with Uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Some of you may recognize this equation as the latitude of a sub satellite point for a circular orbit. I have seen papers that provide the solution, but not the steps.

Given:

1. $\sin(\gamma) = \sin(\theta) \sin(i)$
2. $\theta \sim U(0,2\pi)$

find the PDF as a function of $\gamma$ and $i$, given that $i$ is constant for a given PDF and $ -i < \gamma < i$.

The solution in several texts is

$$f(\gamma) = \frac{\cos\gamma}{\pi\sqrt{\sin^2 i - \sin^2\gamma}}; \qquad  -i < \gamma < i$$

Can anyone provide guidance on the derivation?

Comment: After looking around I have found some documentation about "change of variables" and starting with the know CDF of $\theta$ to calculate the CDF of $f(\gamma)$